# Using both dedicated firewall hardware plus Windows server firewall?

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-firewall

I'm slowly educating myself in servers for a corporate environment (still early in my IT career)

I've been playing around with Windows Firewall and implemented a couple of additional inbound rules to the Windows Firewall; however i know that many companies also use dedicated hardware firewalls. Can someone give me some information about a few things

1) Would using Windows Firewall on a server being good enough for a company?
2) How would you integrate both a dedicated firewall and a Windows firewall so you have an additional layer of security
3) Any additional rules that should be implemented that aren't default; i personally created inbound rules to stop TeamViewer on UDP and TCP (same port)

Been doing all of this on a VM by the way before you all freak out

Answer (score 0):

Hardware firewalls generally sit at the perimeter of the network and prevent external traffic, other than that which you've specially allowed, from entering your network. Software firewalls on the OS I would say are an additional protection which is useful to prevent traffic between nodes on the LAN rather than relying on it as the only firewall. It is fairly typical for administrators to disable the Windows firewall as part of the build process, but I personally like to leave the firewall on and allow only the ports required for the services that server is providing. An good example of why that is good practice is Wannacry, by default all Windows clients and servers have SMB running and admin shares exposed which left them vulnerable to Wannacry if unpatched, having the Windows firewall running protects against that as the SMB service isn't exposed unless it's been explicitly allowed. The downside of having the Windows Firewall ruining is the additional administration required to configure and maintain the firewall rules.